# direct and redirect iframe from relatedlist to detail and back

Tags: apex, visualforce, class, redirect, iframe

I have this visualforce page with 2 iframes in which i want to place a 2 different contact related list and be able to add new contacts on the detail page and be redirected to the related list in the iframe see my example below, is this possible?

```
<apex:page>
 <apex:form >
        <apex:iframe src="/apex/AccountDetailOld?id=0010Y00000WxAd6" scrolling="false" id="Iframe1" width="50%"/>
    <apex:iframe src="/apex/AccountDetailNew?id=0010Y00000WxAd67" scrolling="false" id="Iframe2" width="50%"/>
</apex:form>
```

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
<apex:relatedList list="Contacts"/>
```